# Easy way to set active class with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to find the easiest way to set the active class to the active Navbar point.

My Code looks like this:

```js
function setActive(i) {
    $(document).ready.getElementById(i).addClass("active");
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/main.js"></script>
  <script>
    setActive("contact");
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a id="contact" class="nav-link" href="">Example</a>
</body>
```

Why is this not working?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what does console tell you?

Comment: Classes are added like this `element.classList.add('active')`

Comment: @Wolly300 looks like you are mixing up native js with jQuery on this line `$(document).ready.getElementById(i).addClass("active");` you should pick one and stick with it.

Comment: do you use Jquery ?

Comment: @Abderrahmane Look in the `head` section of the document in the code snippet.

Comment: Ah okay, i gave the answer with pure javascript but you can use .addClass() instease of classList.add()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery, you use `$().addClass()`. You should call the `function` inside `$(document).ready()`, not have the function run only if the document has loaded.

In your `setActive` function, it looks like you are mixing up Javascript and jQuery. You should only use one or the other.

```
$(document).ready.getElementById(i).addClass("active");//this line is a syntax error
```

```css
.active{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  function setActive(i) {
    $('#'+i).addClass("active");
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
      setActive("contact");
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a id="contact" class="nav-link" href="">Example</a>
</body>
```

With pure Javascript, you can use `Element.classList.add()` to add a class to an element.

```css
.active{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<head>
      <script>
      function setActive(i) {
        document.getElementById(i).classList.add("active");
      }
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
          setActive("contact");
      });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <a id="contact" class="nav-link" href="">Example</a>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the contact active you need to this it this way. You already have jQuery in you code so it is more easy.

```
function setActive(tag){
    //This bloc is optinal. It will remove active class from all other elements. You may not need that
    $('body a').removeClass('active');
    //End optional block
    $(`#${tag}`).addClass('active');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    setActive('contact')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please try:

```
function addActive(el){
    document.querySelector(el).classList.add("active");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `setActive("content")` inside main.js inside a ready function

You are also missing the `id` selector (`#`) in your jQuery selector

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setActive("contact");
});

function setActive(id){
  $(`#${id}`).addClass("active");
}
```

```css
.active{
 color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="contact" class="nav-link" href="">Example</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function setActive(i) {
  document.getElementById(i).classList.add("active");
}
    
function setDisable(i) {
  document.getElementById(i).classList.remove("active");
}
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
      <button type="button" onclick="setActive('demo')">
       Activate
      </button>
      <button type="button" onclick="setDisable('demo')">
       Disable
      </button>
      <p id="demo">Here</p>
    </body>
</html>
```